# BCM2835 GPU interrupt handling with FREERTOS

Tags: interrupts, freertos

I am using Raspberry Pi with Freertos. But I dont know how to handle GPU interrutps for UART, I2C, SPI of BCM2835 with Freertos.

So, can anyone give answer about this?